# cURL выдает HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

Tags: парсер, curl

```
$POST = '{"CollectionCountry":33,"CollectionPostcode":"12001","CollectionTown":"CASTELLON/CASTELLO","DeliveryCountry":33,"DeliveryPostcode":"12001","DeliveryTown":"CASTELLON/CASTELLO","RequiresCommercialInvoice":false,"CollectionDate":null,"QuoteValue":null,"Parcels":[{"Weight":5,"Length":null,"Width":null,"Height":null}],"Columns":[{"Header":"SERVICIO 19\'00","Template":"GRID_RESULTS_COLUMN","Endpoint":"/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=1","Description":null,"Feature":null,"IncludeTags":[],"ExcludeTags":[],"hasResults":true,"loading":true},{"Header":"SERVICIO RED","Template":"GRID_RESULTS_COLUMN","Endpoint":"/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=2","Description":null,"Feature":null,"IncludeTags":[],"ExcludeTags":[],"hasResults":true,"loading":true},{"Header":"SERVICIO 48\'00/72\'00","Template":"GRID_RESULTS_COLUMN","Endpoint":"/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=3","Description":null,"Feature":null,"IncludeTags":[],"ExcludeTags":[],"hasResults":true,"loading":true}],"QuoteResultLayout":null,"QuoteType":0,"SortOptions":null,"CurrencyCode":"EUR","Mode":null}';
function poster($url,$fields_string){
$ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Mobile 

Safari/537.36';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$headers = [
    ':authority:www.myenvialia.com',
    ':method:POST',
    ':path:/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=1',
    ':scheme:https',
    'accept:application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'content-length:1051',
    'content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    'origin:https://www.myenvialia.com',
    'referer:https://www.myenvialia.com/precios?col=33&dest=33&cp=12222&dp=13180&ct=AIN&dt=ABENOJAR&p=1~5',
    'requestverificationtoken: 5djSyDsuvbXQ3AlnfsHP-9e2zc5V3nkxh_vwRsTCIMRqWX5dVhYETbicub2U2qV0UjPOtmAADQ34pcEUKeiAG0a4RVc1',
    'user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Mobile Safari/537.36',
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, '__cfduid=d6196a3dd41d92aacee099e6b841c6e5f1490258075; ARRCookie=d8bdc008a4607e6ff76c1bba4628b53b4e1fc75eb59a830e24f4200fde1db4aa; ASP.NET_SessionId=b2ljlsvhhanfsaukvghd4ey2; __RequestVerificationToken=fPxAiIy2ZS8pE3UhI4LsVGAb_O10GDTCwll2QTfD3QBQuSMN7byWE1oyFUxcI81ZTj5NXnAmP41m3z7-CarwjXmJPAg1; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.2.517958312.1490258077; 45520235-VID=172480694937627; 45520235-SKEY=7154258768904926939; HumanClickSiteContainerID_45520235=STANDALONE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
return array($result,$last);
}

print_r(poster('https://www.myenvialia.com/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=1',json_decode($POST)));
```

Получаю

> Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Mon, 10 Apr 2017 19:57:41 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive X-Node: 107 X-Powered-By: ARR/3.0 Server: cloudflare-nginx CF-RAY: 34d846c9a9824ecc-DME [1] => https://www.myenvialia.com/quotes/api/results/column?deliveryTimes=1 )

Что не правильно делаю? :(

Comment: отправленные вами данные точно 1051 размером?

Comment: @teran Все данные брал с браузера.

Comment: Еще заметил когда убираю строчку requestverificationtoken в хедере, ответ на запрос меняется.. Возможно защита по токену?

Comment: а вы думаете токен там для вида что ли?

Comment: Ну не для вида явно) Обойти не получится, да?

Answer (score 0):

*curl* ставит заголовок `Expect` для запросов методом `POST` с размером данных больше 1024 байт

[GitHub](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/9ad034e5a1b2d42acfdbea184736066782c6c635/lib/http.c#L2593-L2594)

Установите заголовок `Expect` пустым явно:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
```